# Possible to combine KeywordQuery and FullTextSqlQuery?

Tags: fulltextsqlquery, keywordquery, keyword

Basically I would like to get all results that would be returned for a `normal keyword query`, but I want to filter those results with a `WHERE` clause.  I tried using [KeywordQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.keywordquery.aspx) or [FullTextSqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.fulltextsqlquery.aspx) but didn't see anything in either that would appear to let me do that.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd suggest that you just use the KeywordQuery, if you ever want to upgrade to FAST then FullTextSqlQuery insn't suppoerted. what kind of WHERE can't you express using KeywordQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can pass in a keyword along with some parameters to filter the results.  Example:

```
KeywordQuery kw = new KeywordQuery();
kw.QueryText = "some keyword (DocumentDate >= 1/1/2009 AND DocumentDate <= 12/31/2009)";
```

will return only results that would be returned for a search on "some keyword" that have a DocumentDate somewhere in 2009.

You can find the details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394509.aspx).

Hope this helps someone!